# Vault Settings are missing. Please import Vault Settings and verify the same

Tags: azure

When i try to get the Azure Recovery Plan, I get:

```
Get-AzureRmSiteRecoveryRecoveryPlan : Operation failed.
ClientRequestId: 
Vault Settings are missing. Please import Vault Settings and verify the same
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzureRmSiteRecoveryRecoveryPlan -Name $name
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureRmSiteRecoveryRecoveryPlan], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.SiteRecovery.GetAzureRmSiteRecoveryRecoveryPlan
```

the rest of my script is:

```
$AzureSubscriptionName = "SubscriptionName"
$vPath = "C:\Path\"

$login = Login-AzureRmAccount
$Subcription = Get-AzureRmSubscription –SubscriptionName $AzureSubscriptionName | Select-AzureRmSubscription

$vault = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault -Name Name -ResourceGroupName rgName

$vFile = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVaultSettingsFile -Vault $vault -Path $vPath


Get-AzureRmSiteRecoveryRecoveryPlan -Name TestASR
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the error log, it seems recovery plan name is not correct. I test in my lab. If I use wrong name, I get same error with you. You had better check recovery plan name.

More information about recovery plan please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/site-recovery-create-recovery-plans#create-a-recovery-plan).

Comment: Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

After getting the vault, you'll need to first set the vault context with the following:

```
Set-AzRecoveryServicesAsrVaultContext -Vault $vault
```